# SCORM playbar shows up without it being needed

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, scorm

How do I make sure 100% that a SCORM course does not contain any playbar regardless of browser type?

I have an issue where the playbar shows up at random, even if it is set to be off in the courses internal settings and the settings of the site it is running off.

Comment: Are you asking from the perspective of the content author or the LMS? Can you add the specific configuration settings that you feel are supposed to dictate the behavior to your question?

Comment: I am asking from the perspective of the LMS, seemingly the internal settings set by the author is sorted and is supposed to stop any playbar to show up, and in the same manner the LMS site has the playbar setting ticked off, still at random and on different browsers the playbar shows up for different clients.